# Define a command where the name has a suffix

Tags: macros

Say I define the command `\newcommand{\d}[1]{\mathrm{d}#1}`.

I can use it like `\d{x}` or `\d{y}`.

Is it possible to define the command `\d`, such that I can use it like `\dx` or `\dy` without an argument?

Comment: No. You can use `\d x` and `\d y`

Comment: Why not? Can't you construct a command name from variables?

Comment: Something similar to `\foreach \letter in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,k,l,m,n,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname d\endcsname{\letter}
}`

Comment: Well, then you'll have two (or more) different commands `\dx` and `\dy`, not a single command `\d` (P.S.: don't use short command names like `\d`; use `\dif` or something like that).  Though in this case you don't need an argument really: `\newcommand\dif{\mathrm{d}}` then `\dif x` will do exactly the same

Comment: That's what I want. I want to define multiple commands that start with `\d` without writing out each one. I expected my above code to work, but it does not.

Comment: It's not a lazy thing. I'm trying to expand my knowledge of LaTeX and ran into a situation where I could.

Comment: With `\foreach` you can do `\foreach \letter in {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,k,l,m,n,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}{\expandafter\xdef\csname d\letter\endcsname{\noexpand\mathrm{d}\letter}}`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you ***don't*** want to redefine `\d`.

I also find no reason for wanting a host of commands, instead of something simpler such as

```
\diff x
```

Anyway, you can define `\da \db ... \dz` in one swoop by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\diff}{}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnn { `a } { `z }
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {`h}{\iow_term:n {Not~redefining~\dh}}
    {`j}{\iow_term:n {Not~redefining~\dj}}
    {`o}{\iow_term:n {Not~redefining~\do}}
    {`p}{\iow_term:n {Not~redefining~\do}}
   }
   {
    \cs_new:cpx { d \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 11 } } { \diff \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 11 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\int_0^1 f(t)\dt = \int_0^1 f(b)\db
\]
\[
\da\db\dc\dd\de\dots\dx\dy\dz
\]

\end{document}
```

You ***don't*** want to redefine `\dh`, `\dj`, `\do` and `\dp`.

[image]

Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: Well, it was you who went through the trouble, so you tell us, was it worth it? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Rhetoric question 

Answer (score 1):

You can define the commands `\da`...`\dz` by the following code:

```
\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\definedif#1{\ifx\relax#1\else \sdef{d#1}{{\rm d}#1}\expandafter\definedif\fi}
\definedif abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\relax

%test
\meaning \dv % macro:->{\rm d}v

\bye
```